# How build a string from specific charaters of string arrays with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Hello every Linq experts,

I would like to know how can I solve the following:

There is a string array:

```
string[] words={"a#p#e","#pp#e","a##le"};
```

How can I get the word 'apple' by Linq?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you need to use LINQ? I'm not sure I would in this case... it would be feasible with `Aggregate`, but it's not an obvious choice...

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: Unfortunately Linq solution is the expectations.

Comment: As Daniel said, it would be helpful to see your current efforts in Linq.

Comment: I don't have efforts because one my main problem is I don't know how can I reach the characters in the string by Linq.

Comment: Is this an exam question? How would you try to solve this if LINQ wasn't mentioned? In an exam question you *will* be asked to explain why something works. If you can't even show that you understand what the data means (much less how to solve the problem), you will fail.

Comment: I would initialize that string array a little more explicitly.. `string[] words = new string[] {"a#p#e","#pp#e","a##le"};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`words.SelectMany(ar=>ar.Select((c,i)=>new{Index=i, Letter = c}).Where(o=>char.IsLetter(o.Letter))).OrderBy(o=>o.Index).GroupBy(o=>o).Select(g=>g.Key);`

Most likely this can be simplified, but well, it works (put together quickly in LinqPad).

This assumes you're only working with letters  (can be modified to use `char.IsLetterOrDigit`), or use other filtering in `Where`.

Also, especially for @MarkPeters, a query syntax, properly named version:

```
from partialWord in words
from characterWithPosition in partialWord.Select((character, position) => new{character,position})
where char.IsLetter(characterWithPosition.character)
orderby characterWithPosition.position
group characterWithPosition by characterWithPosition into  allCharactersWithPositions
let singleCharacterWithPosition = allCharactersWithPositions.Key
select singleCharacterWithPosition.character
```

Comment: A fine answer given the constraints (must use Linq) but I hope that I never have to maintain code like this.  Beautifully, completely, illegible.

Comment: @MarkPeters, that's because of all the anonymous Expression delegate initialization and usage going on here. It's a lot more readable if you define the expressions prior to the `words.SelectMany`.  Allows for reusability as well..

Comment: @MarkPeters I'll definitely NOT argue with that :) I'm 99.9% sure the question is an exam/homework one, so I didn't strive for maintainability ;)

Comment: actually, looking back on this, in the first code snippet..  aren't you just ending up with an `IEnumerable<object>` as a result, where object is your anonymous type? and the second one, you've performed a `select` to retrieve that `char` from the `anonymous type`'s `char` property (`Letter`/`character`)... it still needs to be either aggregated to a string ..or used to construct a new `string` (i.e. `new string(char[])` ), right?

Comment: Yup, I was just `.Dump()`ing the enumerable in the first snippet in LinqPad ;) The second produces IEnumerable<char> which indeed needs `.ToArray()` and a `String(char[])` constructor :) `String.Concat` also can be used, but it's marginally slower :)

Comment: Hello guys, I used this for create the string:

    message = String.Concat(Result.Select(c => c.Letter));

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
string[] words = { "a#p#e", "#pp#e", "a##le" };

var apple = words
    .Aggregate(
        (str1, str2) => { return String.Concat(str1.Zip(str2, 
            (c1, c2) => c1 == '#' ? c2 : c1).ToArray());
        });
```

It works by checking whether there are any not-wanted characters in the first string and replacing them with the corresponding characters from the second string. The merged string is then passed to the next iteration, where the next two strings are merged. Finally the result is returned.

Comment: Good solution but the second `return` is redundant your query would be more simple by removing it like this:`return String.Concat(str1.Zip(str2,(c1, c2) => c1 == '#' ? c2 : c1).ToArray());`.

Comment: @user2946329 I didn't notice that, I just changed it, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

@mrbraitwistle's answer is the proper solution; performing `IEnumerable<char>.Zip` method within a `IEnumerable<string>.Aggregate` method

---

This following answer provides explicit type definitions to the parts of @Gerino's answer, which uses quite a bit of anonyomous types and delegates; Additioanlly, this answer utilizes `Linq.Expressions` and `IQueryable<T>`;

There is a catch though, it is in the `GetHashCode` of `IndexLetterPair` type below.

---

We'll create a concrete type instead of declaring the anonymous type `new { Index = i, Letter = c }`; however, the `GroupBy` will not function properly unless we override the `GetHashCode` method of `object` (of which our type inherits).  We are also going to implement the IEquatable interface (where T is another IndexLetterPair), this interface will be utlized by the `IQueryable<T>.GroupBy` method.

Additionally, well override the `object.Equal` method as well - though it is likely unnecessary to do so since the `GetHashCode` is overriden.

```
public class IndexLetterPair IEquatable<IndexLetterPair>
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public char Letter { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return new { Index = this.Index, Letter = this.Letter }.GetHashCode();
    }

    // (new IndexLetterPair() as object).Equals(new IndexLetterPair());
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return (this.GetHashCode() == obj.GetHashCode());        
    }

    // new IndexLetterPair().Equals(new IndexLetterPair());
    public bool Equals(IndexLetterPair other)
    {
        return (this.GetHashCode() == other.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

---

For convience, were going to declare an extension class and method of `IQueryable<string>` that executes/declares the sequence of our defined expressions.

```
using Linq.Expressions;
public static class MyQueryableStringExtensions
{
    readonly static Func<char, int, IndexLetterPair> SelectCharIndexPairingClause = (c, i) => new IndexLetterPair() { Index = i, Letter = c };
    readonly static Func<IndexLetterPair, bool> WhereIsLetter = (dyn) => char.IsLetter(dyn.Letter);
    readonly static Expression<Func<string, IEnumerable<IndexLetterPair>>> ManyClause = (arr) => arr.Select(SelectCharIndexPairingClause).Where(WhereIsLetter);
    readonly static Expression<Func<IndexLetterPair, int>> OrderByIndexClause = (pairing) => pairing.Index;
    readonly static Expression<Func<IndexLetterPair, IndexLetterPair>> GroupByClause = (pairing) => pairing;
    // if IEquatable<IndexLetterPair> is implemented ? uses IEquatable<IndexLetterPair>.Equals : (IndexLetterPair() as object).Equals
    readonly static Expression<Func<IGrouping<IndexLetterPair, IndexLetterPair>, IndexLetterPair>> GroupSelectKeyClause = (pairing) => pairing.Key;

    public static IQueryable<char> SelectManyGroupedLetterChars(this IQueryable<string> words)
    {
        return words.SelectMany(ManyClause)
            .OrderBy(OrderByIndexClause)
            .GroupBy(GroupByClause)
            .Select(GroupSelectKeyClause)
            .Select((pair) => pair.Letter);
    }
}
```

---

```
 string[] words = new string[] { "a#p#e", "#pp#e", "a##le" };                        

 IQueryable<string> queryableWords = words.AsQueryable();    
 IQueryable<char> queryGroupedLetterChars = queryableWords.SelectManyGroupedLetterChars();

 // string(char[]);
 string word = new string(queryGroupedLetterChars.ToArray());
```

---

Comment: there are pros and cons to each approach: for instance, what happens if a `string` within the `string[]` differ in length relative to the other `string` instances in the array?. review `Zip` method remarks: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx